# Action function chaining onLoad and oncomplete to call a SOQL Query

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I have 13 to 14 sections on a page. I want to call them using actionfunction asynchronusly using queue or chaining mechanism. 
So that only one section is called at a time. And performance of page is enhanced. 
Has any one done action function chaining ?
Please help

Here is code :

```
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.Leads_Requiring_Attention}"  id="LeadPB" rendered="{!IF(UnacceptedLeads.SIZE==0 && AcceptedLeads.SIZE==0 && QualifiedLeads.SIZE==0 , 'false', 'true')}" >

    <!-- LEAD SECTION 1 : UNACCEPTED LEADS -->
    <apex:pageBlocksection title="Unaccepted leads – assigned but not accepted  ({!$Label.Record_Count}: {!NoOfEntriesFound}){!$Label.AlertUnacceptedleads}"   id="LeadBlock2" collapsible="false" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(UnacceptedLeads.SIZE>0, 'true', 'false')}" >            
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!UnacceptedLeads}" var="lead" id="Leadtable2"   style="width:100%" >

            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:outputlink value="/{!lead.Id}" >
                   <!-- <apex:param name="leadId" value="{!lead.Id}"/> -->
                     {!lead.Name}
                 </apex:outputlink>
             </apex:column> 
             <apex:column headerValue="Company" value="{!lead.Company}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Lead Source" value="{!lead.LeadSource}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Lead Source Details" value="{!lead.Lead_Source_Details_del__c}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Created Date " value="{!lead.CreatedDate}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Days Open" value="{!lead.Days_Open_Unaccepted_leads__c}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Owner Name" value="{!lead.Owner.Name}" rendered="{!IF(ownername, 'true', 'false')}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <!-- LEAD SECTION 1 : PAGINATION -->            
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="font-weight: bold;" id="pgtable1" >
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rerender="Leadtable2,pgtable1" immediate="true" status="Loading1" ><font color="blue">Previous</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rerender="Leadtable2,pgtable1" immediate="true" status="Loading1"><font color="blue">Next</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:outputText value="Page {!pageNumber} of {!pages} " />

        </apex:panelGrid>
        <apex:actionStatus id="Loading1"  >
        <apex:facet name="start" ><font color="red">Loading the data, please wait....</font></apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop"><font color="blue">Data Loaded ,Thanks for patience!</font></apex:facet> 
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </apex:pageBlocksection> 

    <!-- LEAD SECTION 2 : ACCEPTED LEADS -->
    <apex:pageBlocksection title="Accepted Stuck leads – in a 
               or contacting status for more than 7 days ({!$Label.Record_Count}: {!NoOfEntriesFoundAL}). Review to see if it can progress or if it should be closed " id="LeadBlock3" collapsible="false" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(AcceptedLeads.SIZE>0, 'true', 'false')}" >

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AcceptedLeads}" var="lead" id="Leadtable3"  rows="5" style="width:100%">

                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:outputlink value="/{!lead.Id}" >
                       <!-- <apex:param name="leadId" value="{!lead.Id}"/> -->
                     {!lead.Name}
                 </apex:outputlink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Company" value="{!lead.Company}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Lead Source" value="{!lead.LeadSource}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Lead Source Details" value="{!lead.Lead_Source_Details_del__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Created Date " value="{!lead.CreatedDate}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Accepted Date " value="{!lead.Accepted_Date__c}"/>
                <!-- <apex:column headerValue="Days Since Accepted Old" value="{!lead.Untouched_Duration__c}"/> -->
                 <apex:column headerValue="Days Since Accepted " value="{!lead.Days_Since_Accepted__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Owner Name" value="{!lead.Owner.Name}" rendered="{!IF(ownername, 'true', 'false')}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <!-- LEAD SECTION 2 : PAGINATION -->           
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="font-weight: bold;" id="pgtable3">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previousAL}" rerender="Leadtable3,pgtable3" immediate="true" status="Loading3"><font color="blue">Previous</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!nextAL}" rerender="Leadtable3,pgtable3" immediate="true" status="Loading3"><font color="blue">Next</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:outputText value="Page {!pageNumberAL} of {!pagesAL} " />

        </apex:panelGrid>
        <apex:actionStatus id="Loading3"  >
        <apex:facet name="start" ><font color="red">Loading the data, please wait....</font></apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop"><font color="blue">Data Loaded ,Thanks for patience!</font></apex:facet> 
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </apex:pageBlocksection> 

        <!-- LEAD SECTION 3 : QUALIFIED LEADS --> 
        <apex:pageBlocksection title="Qualified Stuck leads – in qualified status for more than 30 days ({!$Label.Record_Count}: {!NoOfEntriesFoundQL}).  Review to see if it can be converted to an opportunity or if it should be closed" id="LeadBlock4" collapsible="false" columns="1"  rendered="{!IF(QualifiedLeads.SIZE>0, 'true', 'false')}">            

           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!QualifiedLeads}" var="lead" id="Leadtable4"  style="width:100%">

              <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                  <apex:outputlink value="/{!lead.Id}" >
                     <!-- <apex:param name="leadId" value="{!lead.Id}"/> -->
                      {!lead.Name}
                  </apex:outputlink>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Company" value="{!lead.Company}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Lead Source" value="{!lead.LeadSource}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Lead Source Details" value="{!lead.Lead_Source_Details_del__c}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Created Date " value="{!lead.CreatedDate}"/>
               <apex:column headerValue="Accepted Date " value="{!lead.Accepted_Date__c}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Days Stuck" value="{!lead.Untouched_Duration__c}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Owner Name" value="{!lead.Owner.Name}" rendered="{!IF(ownername, 'true', 'false')}"/> 
          </apex:pageBlockTable>

         <!-- LEAD SECTION 3 : PAGINATION -->           
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="font-weight: bold;" id="pgtable4">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previousQL}" rerender="Leadtable4,pgtable4" immediate="true" status="Loading"><font color="blue">Previous</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!nextQL}" rerender="Leadtable4,pgtable4" immediate="true" status="Loading"><font color="blue">Next</font></apex:commandLink>

            <apex:outputText value="Page {!pageNumberQL} of {!pagesQL}" />

        </apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:actionStatus id="Loading"  >
        <apex:facet name="start" ><font color="red">Loading the data, please wait....</font></apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop"><font color="blue">Data Loaded ,Thanks for patience!</font></apex:facet> 
        </apex:actionStatus>

        </apex:pageBlocksection> 


        <!-- ***********************              LEAD SECTION  THREE ENDS              ************************************************************************  -->

</apex:pageBlock>



<apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.OpportunitiesRequiringAttention}" rendered="{!IF(Oppsclosepast.SIZE==0 , 'false', 'true')}">   

    <!-- ***********************               SECTION ONE  :  Opportunities_with_close_dates_in_the_past               ************************************************************************  -->
        <apex:pageBlocksection title="{!$Label.Opportunities_with_close_dates_in_the_past}  ({!$Label.Record_Count}: {!NoOfEntriesFoundCPO}). Update the close date or close it" id="OppBlock2" collapsible="false" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(Oppsclosepast.SIZE>0, 'true', 'false')}"> 

            <apex:pageBlockTable title="{!$Label.Opportunities_with_close_dates_in_the_past}"  value="{!Oppsclosepast}" var="opp" id="table2" style="width:100%" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Name">
                <apex:outputlink value="/{!opp.Id}">
                <!--  <apex:param name="oppId" value="{!opp.Id}"/> -->
                  {!opp.Name}
                </apex:outputlink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!opp.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Stage" value="{!opp.StageName}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount" value="{!opp.Amount}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Estimated Close Date" value="{!opp.CloseDate}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Days Past Estimated Close Date" value="{!opp.Age__c}"/>

                <apex:column headerValue="Owner Name" value="{!opp.Owner.Name}" rendered="{!IF(ownername, 'true', 'false')}"/>    
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

         <!-- OPPORTUNITY SECTION 1 : PAGINATION -->           
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="font-weight: bold;" id="OppPgtable2">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previousCPO}" rerender="table2,OppPgtable2" immediate="true" status="LoadingOpp2"><font color="blue">Previous</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!nextCPO}" rerender="table2,OppPgtable2" immediate="true" status="LoadingOpp2"><font color="blue">Next</font></apex:commandLink>
            <apex:outputText value="Page {!pageNumberCPO} of {!pagesCPO} " />

        </apex:panelGrid>
        <apex:actionStatus id="LoadingOpp2"  >
        <apex:facet name="start" ><font color="red">Loading the data, please wait....</font></apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop"><font color="blue">Data Loaded ,Thanks for patience!</font></apex:facet> 
        </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:pageBlocksection> 





 <!-- ***********************              EMPTY SECTION                       ************************************************************************  -->
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.No_Records_to_Display}"  rendered="{!IF( AcceptedLeads.SIZE==0 && UnacceptedLeads.SIZE==0 && QualifiedLeads.SIZE==0 && Oppsclosepast.SIZE == 0 && Oppsclosein30days.SIZE == 0 && Opps.SIZE == 0 && Oppswithoutcontacts.SIZE == 0 && OppsSameStage60days.SIZE == 0 && OppswithoutTask.SIZE == 0 && OppsByStage.SIZE == 0 && OppsInactiveOwners.SIZE == 0, 'true', 'false')}">
        <style type="text/css">
        p { color: #f65; font-weight: bold; }
        </style>
        <p>{!$Label.Great_job_There_are_no_records_that_need_your_attention_today}</p>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form> 
<!-- ********* To include task functionality  with old implementation ****  <apex:include pageName="ViewMyAttentionTask"/> -->
```

---

Controller :

public class AttentionController {

```
public boolean ownername{get;set;}
static Set<String> UserIdsSet= new Set<String>();
public List<Lead> leadResult{get;set;}
public List<Opportunity> oppResult{get;set;}
static Set<String> UserIdsSetInActive= new Set<String>();

/******** Constructor **************/
public AttentionController(){
    UserIdInfo();
    UserIdInfoInactive();
}
/***************Comman methods starts **************************************************/

/*
    Method Name :   UserIdInfo()
    Usage : FOR GMS profiles there is criteria for User type and Region used to filter Query
    Component :  Custom Settings : Sales_Representative__c
                 Field : Manager2. 
    Migration details : Migrated custom settings and Manager2 feild data as well.
*/
public void UserIdInfo()
{
    if(UserIdsSet.size() == 0) {    
        Map <String,Sales_Representative__c> allSalesRep =Sales_Representative__c.getall();
        if(!allSalesRep.containsKey(UserInfo.getProfileId()))
        {

            String userId =UserInfo.getUserId();
            String UserIds ;// FOR GMS profiles there is criteria for User type and Region so filtering Query
            if(UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00e80000001C7XOAA0'){

                UserIds = 'Select Id From User where Manager2__c=\''+userId+'\' AND IsActive=True AND Region__c = \'EMEA\' AND UserType =\'Outside Sales Rep\' ';
            } else if (UserInfo.getProfileId()== '00e80000001C7XMAA0')  {
                 UserIds = 'Select Id From User where Manager2__c=\''+userId+'\' AND IsActive=True AND Region__c = \'EMEA\' AND UserType =\'Outside Sales Manager\' ';
            } 
            else{
                 UserIds = 'Select Id From User where Manager2__c=\''+userId+'\' AND IsActive=True';
            }    
            System.debug('-----------<><><><>< UserIds ' +UserIds);

            List<User> UserIdsList= Database.query(UserIds);

            System.debug('UserIdsList****-------:'+UserIdsList.Size());
            UserIdsSet.add(userId);
            for(User ur: UserIdsList){
                UserIdsSet.add(ur.Id);

                ownername=true;

            }

        }
        else{
             UserIdsSet.add(UserInfo.getUserId());
             ownername=false;
        }
             System.debug('UserIdsSet****-------:'+UserIdsSet.Size());  
             System.debug(UserIdsSet);
    }   
}

/*
    Method Name :   UserIdInfoInactive()
    Usage :This method returns all inactive users satisfing below criteria
           FOR GMS profiles there is criteria for User type and Region used to filter Query
    Component :  Custom Settings : Sales_Representative__c
                 Field : Manager2. 
    Migration details : Migrated custom settings and Manager2 feild data as well.
*/

 public void UserIdInfoInactive()
{
    if(UserIdsSetInActive.size() == 0) {
        Map <String,Sales_Representative__c> allSalesRep =Sales_Representative__c.getall();
        if(!allSalesRep.containsKey(UserInfo.getProfileId()))
        {

            String userId =UserInfo.getUserId();
           String UserIds ;// FOR GMS profiles there is criteria for User type and Region so filtering Query
            if(UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00e80000001C7XOAA0'){

                UserIds = 'Select Id From User where Manager2__c=\''+userId+'\' AND  Region__c = \'EMEA\' AND UserType =\'Outside Sales Rep\' ';
            } else if (UserInfo.getProfileId()== '00e80000001C7XMAA0')  {
                 UserIds = 'Select Id From User where Manager2__c=\''+userId+'\' AND Region__c = \'EMEA\' AND UserType =\'Outside Sales Manager\' ';
            } 
            else{
                 UserIds = 'Select Id From User where Manager2__c=\''+userId+'\' ' ;
            }    
            System.debug('-----------<><><><>< UserIds ' +UserIds);

            List<User> UserIdsList= Database.query(UserIds);

             System.debug('UserIdsList****-------:'+UserIdsList.Size());

            for(User ur: UserIdsList){
                UserIdsSetInActive.add(ur.Id);

                ownername=true;

            }
            UserIdsSetInActive.add(userId);

        }
        else{
             UserIdsSetInActive.add(UserInfo.getUserId());
             ownername=false;
        }
             System.debug('UserIdsSetInActive****-------:'+UserIdsSetInActive.Size());  

    }    
}
/*
    Method Name :   getCommaSeperatedStringList()
    Usage : Convert Set to comma seprated string.

*/
public static String getCommaSeperatedStringList(Set<String> stringSet) {
    String commaSeperatedString = '';
    if(stringSet != null && stringSet.size() > 0) {
        commaSeperatedString += '(';
        Boolean isFirstValue = true;
        for (String value : stringSet) {

            if(isFirstValue) {
                commaSeperatedString += '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value) + '\'';
                isFirstValue = false;
            } else {
                commaSeperatedString += ', \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value) + '\'';
            } 
        }
        commaSeperatedString += ')';
    }
    return commaSeperatedString;
} 

/*********************** Unaccepted Leads Section 1 In VF****************************************/

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setConUnacceptedLeads {
    get {
        String queryUnacceptedLeads = '';
        if(setConUnacceptedLeads == null) {
            if(UserIdsSet.Size()>0){
                queryUnacceptedLeads = 'SELECT  Name, CreatedDate ,Company,LeadSource, Lead_Source_Details_del__c,Owner.Name, Days_Open_Unaccepted_leads__c FROM Lead WHERE Sales_Accepted__c = FALSE AND Status IN (\'Contacting\',\'New\',\'Qualified\') AND OwnerId IN '+getCommaSeperatedStringList(UserIdsSet) + 'ORDER BY Days_Open_Unaccepted_leads__c DESC LIMIT 200 ' ;
                List<Lead> leadResult = Database.query(queryUnacceptedLeads);
                setConUnacceptedLeads = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(leadResult);
                setConUnacceptedLeads.setPageSize(5);
            }
        }
        return setConUnacceptedLeads;
    }
    set;
}

// Initialize setConUnacceptedLeads and return a list of records
public List<Lead> getUnacceptedLeads() {
    List<Lead> temp = new List<Lead>();
    if(setConUnacceptedLeads != null)
        return (List<Lead>) setConUnacceptedLeads.getRecords();
    else
        /** Temporary Fix ***/        
        return temp;        
}

/********** Pagination Methods ***********************/
public Integer pageNumber{
    get {
        return setConUnacceptedLeads.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}
public PageReference next() {
    Integer p = setConUnacceptedLeads.getPageNumber();
    if(hasNext) {
        setConUnacceptedLeads.setPageNumber(p+1);

    }
    return null;
}

public Integer getNoOfEntriesFound() {
    Integer num = setConUnacceptedLeads.getResultSize();

    return num ;
}

public PageReference previous() {
   Integer p = setConUnacceptedLeads.getPageNumber();
   if(hasPrevious) {
        setConUnacceptedLeads.setPageNumber(p-1);   
    }
    return null;
}

public Boolean hasPrevious {

    get {
        return setConUnacceptedLeads.getHasPrevious();
    }
}

public Boolean hasNext {
    get {
        return setConUnacceptedLeads.getHasNext();

    }
}
public Integer pages
{
   get{

     pages = setConUnacceptedLeads.getResultSize()/setConUnacceptedLeads.getPageSize();
     system.debug('>>>>>>' + pages);
     if(math.mod(setConUnacceptedLeads.getResultSize(),5) == 0)
        return (pages);
     else   
        return (pages+1);
   }
   set;
}
/*********************************** End UnAccepted Leads : Section One Ends**********************************/



/********************************** Accepted Leads Section2 In VF *****************************/
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setConAcceptedLeads {
    get {
        String queryAcceptedLeads = '';
        if(setConAcceptedLeads == null) {
            if(UserIdsSet.Size()>0){
                queryAcceptedLeads = 'SELECT  Name, CreatedDate ,Company,LeadSource, Lead_Source_Details_del__c, Owner.Name,Days_Since_Accept__c,Accepted_Date__c,Untouched_Duration__c,Days_Since_Accepted__c FROM Lead WHERE Sales_Accepted__c=True  AND Status IN (\'Contacting\',\'New\') AND Days_Since_Accepted__c > 7 AND OwnerId IN '+getCommaSeperatedStringList(UserIdsSet)+' ORDER BY Untouched_Duration__c DESC ';
                leadResult = Database.query(queryAcceptedLeads);
                setConAcceptedLeads = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(leadResult);
                setConAcceptedLeads.setPageSize(5);
            }
        }

        return setConAcceptedLeads;
    }
    set;
}

public List<Lead> getAcceptedLeads() {
    List<Lead> temp = new List<Lead>();
    if(setConAcceptedLeads != null)
        return (List<Lead>) setConAcceptedLeads.getRecords();
    else
        /** Temporary Fix **/        
        return temp;        
}

/********** Pagination Methods ***********************/
public Integer pageNumberAL{
    get {
        return setConAcceptedLeads.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}

public PageReference nextAL() {
    Integer p = setConAcceptedLeads.getPageNumber();
    if(hasNextAL) {
        setConAcceptedLeads.setPageNumber(p+1);
    }
    return null; 
}

public Integer getNoOfEntriesFoundAL() {

    Integer num = setConAcceptedLeads.getResultSize();
    return num ;
}

public PageReference previousAL() {
   Integer p = setConAcceptedLeads.getPageNumber();

    if(hasPreviousAL) {
        setConAcceptedLeads.setPageNumber(p-1);

    }

    return null;
}

public Boolean hasPreviousAL {
    get {
        return setConAcceptedLeads.getHasPrevious();
    }
}

public Boolean hasNextAL {
    get {
        return setConAcceptedLeads.getHasNext();        
    }
}
public Integer pagesAL{

   get{
       pagesAL = setConAcceptedLeads.getResultSize()/setConAcceptedLeads.getPageSize();

       if(math.mod(setConAcceptedLeads.getResultSize(),5) == 0)
        return (pagesAL);
       else
        return (pagesAL+1); 
   }
   set;
}


 /*********************** Qualified Leads Section 3 In VF****************************************/

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setConQualifiedLeads {
    get {
        String queryQualifiedLeads = '';
        if(setConQualifiedLeads == null) {
            if(UserIdsSet.Size()>0){
                queryQualifiedLeads = 'SELECT  Name, CreatedDate ,Company,LeadSource, Lead_Source_Details_del__c, Owner.Name,Days_Stuck__c ,Untouched_Duration__c,Accepted_Date__c FROM Lead WHERE Status = \'Qualified\' AND Untouched_Duration__c >= 30 AND OwnerId IN '+getCommaSeperatedStringList(UserIdsSet)+' ORDER BY Untouched_Duration__c DESC LIMIT 200';
                List<Lead> leadResult = Database.query(queryQualifiedLeads);
                setConQualifiedLeads = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(leadResult);
                setConQualifiedLeads.setPageSize(5);
            }
        }
        return setConQualifiedLeads;
    }
    set;
}


public List<Lead> getQualifiedLeads() {
    List<Lead> temp = new List<Lead>();
    if(setConQualifiedLeads != null)
        return (List<Lead>) setConQualifiedLeads.getRecords();
    else
        /** Temporary Fix ***/        
        return temp;        
}

/********** Pagination Methods ***********************/
public Integer pageNumberQL{
    get {
        return setConQualifiedLeads.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}
public PageReference nextQL() {
    Integer p = setConQualifiedLeads.getPageNumber();
    if(hasNextQL) {
        setConQualifiedLeads.setPageNumber(p+1);

    }
    return null;
}

public Integer getNoOfEntriesFoundQL() {
    Integer num = setConQualifiedLeads.getResultSize();

    return num ;
}

public PageReference previousQL() {
   Integer p = setConQualifiedLeads.getPageNumber();
   if(hasPreviousQL) {
        setConQualifiedLeads.setPageNumber(p-1);    
    }
    return null;
}

public Boolean hasPreviousQL {

    get {
        return setConQualifiedLeads.getHasPrevious();
    }
}

public Boolean hasNextQL {
    get {
        return setConQualifiedLeads.getHasNext();

    }
}
public Integer pagesQL
{
   get{
     pagesQL = setConQualifiedLeads.getResultSize()/setConQualifiedLeads.getPageSize();
     system.debug('>>>>>>' + pagesQL);
     if(math.mod(setConQualifiedLeads.getResultSize(),5) == 0)
        return (pagesQL);
     else
        return (pagesQL+1); 

   }
   set;
}
/*********************************** End Qualified Leads : Section One Ends**********************************/
```

}//End of class

Answer (score 2):

You can try to call actionFunction sequentially after the section is loaded, something like:

Class:

```
public Boolean param1 {!get;set;}
public Boolean param2 {!get;set;}

public MyClass(){
    param1 = false;
    param2 = false;
}
```

Page:

```
<!-- This one loads the first panel and then calls the next function that will load the second panel -->
<apex:actionFunction action="{!loadPanel}"
                     name="load1"
                     reRender="panel1"
                     oncomplete="load2(true);">
    <apex:param name="p1" assignTo="{!param1}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!loadPanel}"
                     name="load2"
                     reRender="panel2">
    <apex:param name="p2" assignTo="{!param2}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>


<apex:outputPanel id="panel1">
    <apex:outputPanel id="section1" rendered="{!param1}">
    ....
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="panel2">
    <apex:outputPanel id="section1" rendered="{!param2}">
    ....
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- Loading the first panel -->
<script>
    load1(true);
</script>
```

Comment: Not able to chain the execution with SOQL...:(

Answer (score 1):

I would make each section as components, so that each and every component can get their own execution context and we can control when these components can be loaded using Javascript.

```
<apex:page controller="LeadController" sidebar="false">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.YourResources, 'js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-1.8.2.js')}" />
    <c:component1 />
    <c:component2 />
    <c:component3 />
    <c:component4 />
    <c:component5 />

<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {
    Component1ActionFunction();
    Component2ActionFunction();
    Component3ActionFunction();
    Component4ActionFunction();
    Component5ActionFunction();
}
</script>   
</apex:page>
```

and in the "**componentSection1**" looks like,

```
<apex:component id="component1" controller="component1Controller">
    <apex:outputPanel id="Component1OutputPanel">
        <!-- Do stuff here-->
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="Component1ActionFunction" action="{!YourCustomMethodinController}"    rerender="Component1OutputPanel"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

the "**componentSectionController1**" looks like this

```
public with sharing class PartnersBySECController {

    public PartnersBySECController(){
         //Do not call any methods here.
    }

    public void YourCustomMethodinController(){

    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this pattern ensures that we get the lazy loading in the VF pages and also get seperate execution context and its limits for each and every component.